# add attributes to image woocommerce product

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I would need a little help if I could. I have a store type web site made in wordpress. From anywhere on the site you want to enter the product page you can do it only if you click on the title. I want to make it possible to enter the product page and if you click on the image.
Below I attach the images with the code.
https://airless-consulting.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/imagine_produs.jpg
https://airless-consulting.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/titlu_produs.jpg
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a link on the image? Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>">
    <img src="" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: This is what the customer wants, he wants to enter the product and clicking on the image not only on the product name. I'm fine with what he sent me, only he doesn't want to take my picture anymore. I attach the result as well as the code
https://airless-consulting.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/sectiune-actualizata.jpg
https://airless-consulting.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/rezultat_impartial.jpg

Comment: You have a mistake in your html. <img src="src="

Comment: I solved it thanks to your help. That's exactly what he told me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, please accept my answer please ;)